# Graphic bug when writing PNG from BITMAP in memory

Tags: c++, bitmap, rgb, libpng

I'm using libpng to convert a BITMAP to a PNG (all in memory) and it does create the image but with some visual bugs.

[image]

The background has a vertical colored line that appears to be cyan, magenta and yellow and the image is spread out horizontally so 1/4 is missing to the right. The **BITMAP** is created using **CDC** and drawing to a `CBitmap`. Drawing is done in **RGB** so when the **BITMAP** is passed to the **PNG** function I use **BITMAPINFOHEADER** with `biCompression` set to `BI_RGB`. In the libpng settings, I used 8 for the bit-depth and `PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB`. I originally thought the **BITMAP** was in **CMYK** which is what caused the problem but it seems to be in **RGB**. Could there be a conversion problem? When I convert the same **Bitmap** to **JPEG** everything is perfect.

**BITMAPINFOHEADER** :

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER oBitmapInfoHeader;
memset(&oBitmapInfoHeader, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
oBitmapInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
oBitmapInfoHeader.biWidth = width;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biHeight = height * -1;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount = bitmap.bmPlanes * bitmap.bmBitsPixel; //initializes at 32
oBitmapInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
oBitmapInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
```

I'm using a **BYTE** array:

```
const uint32_t stride = width * 4;
png_byte *row = (png_byte *)poBitmapInfoHeader + (oBitmapInfoHeader.biSize + iColors * sizeof(RGBQUAD));

for (uint32_t y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    png_write_row(png_ptr, row);
    row += stride;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're willing to help you. Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55122811/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: You have a padding issue? Is the bitmap 24bpp or 32bpp? Is the bitmap BGRA or BGR or RGB or RGBA?

Comment: `stride = width * 4;` looks like a bold assumption, also i'm not sure whether `png_write_row` correctly interprets buffer passed (or rather `row` does not contain data in the format that png expects).

Comment: @Brandon the handler initializes at 32 and if I set it to 24 the `GetDIBits` function doesn't work.

@VTT I have a callback function that deals with writing the bytes. If I change the 4 to 3 the image is much worse and any other value causes an access violation. I suspect the Bitmap should be 24bpp but `GetDIBits` doesn't return anything if `biBitCount` isn't set to 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

biBitCount is indeed 24

```
oBitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount = 24;// bitmap.bmPlanes * bitmap.bmBitsPixel;
```

`GetDIBits` failed because it started a bit too far

```
(LPBYTE)poBitmapInfoHeader + (oBitmapInfoHeader.biSize + iColors * 3),//sizeof(RGBQUAD)),   // address for bitmap bits
```

Then a stride with 3bpp works

```
const uint32_t stride = (width * 3);
```